# Batch file to create the directories structure

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, directory-structure

I need a help to create a batch file in Windows. I have a job to execute in the Jenkins and I need to create the directories structure below:

```
Product_4.1.1 --> this value is pass by parameter
      |_4.1.1.00 --> I need remove the first part (Product_) and create a new sequence      
      |_4.1.1.01 --> I execute the job again, I need to create a new one directory
```

I created this process with shell linux, but in Windows I don't have sucess.

Could you help me, about this?

Comment: Have you checked `md /?` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show your batch code even if not succesful.
Provided there are no underscores in `Product` this should do:

```
@Echo off
:: Set Arg=%~1
set Arg=Product_4.1.1
Set "Version=%Arg:*_=_%"
Echo %Arg% %Version%
Set SubVer=100
:loop
If exist "%Version%.%SubVer:~-2%" (Set /A SubVer+=1 & goto :loop)
Echo Create "%Version%.%SubVer:~-2%"
Md "%Version%.%SubVer:~-2%"
```